# read entire .m file (from bundle) as a string in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to read entire .m file in a string using code:

```
NSString* fullFileName = @"file.m";
NSString* fileName = [[fullFileName lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString* extension = [fullFileName pathExtension];
NSString* filePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:extension];
NSString* fileTextContent=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

But it returns `null`.
Is it possible to read .m file from bundle in a string in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you should make sure the .m file is in the bundle first (they aren't by default).

Right click on the app under the products folder in Xcode, select "Reveal in Finder", then right click on the app in finder and select "Show Package contents" to see what's in the bundle.

If you need to add it, you can do that under the project settings in xcode > build phases > copy files phase.

Including .m files in the bundle would be somewhat strange though. There's almost certainly a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. Maybe if you went into more detail on what that is, people could suggest them.